# Mediation effect using Hayes

Tags: interaction, mediation

In my study, path a, b, c and C' all are significant in the Hayes mediation model 4. However, the effect size  of path b (M on Y) is .08 , path c (X on Y is .05 ) and path a (X on M is .3). Also the c' has increased instead of decreasing or being zero.

I had earlier reported that the results showed a significant indirect effect of X on Y via M (b= -.1267, 95% BCa CI [-.1997, -.0556]).

```
Indirect effect of X on Y
          Effect    Boot SE   BootLLCI   BootULCI
M.COM     -.1267      .0357     -.2007     -.0587


Normal theory tests for indirect effect
     Effect         se          Z          p
     -.1267      .0340    -3.7263      .0002
```

The moderation effect at three levels of M were also significant. F (3, 479) = 17.28, p < 0.001, R2= .0977), but with a very small effect size. At all three levels of M, there was a significant relationship between X and Y . For example, at low levels, (b= .29, t (479) = 5.06, p <.001); At medium levels  (b= .41, t (479)= 7.16, p <.001), and at high levels of commitment (b =.52, t (479)= 6.67, p <.001).

Shall  I report commitment to be a mediator / moderator or both or none (due to small effect size). The indirect effect of M  is significant.